# I have a series of netcdf files of sst data. I want to compute sst gradient to locate the oceanic front

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-xarray

```
`sst_gradient = xr.Dataset({'sst_gradient':(['lat','lon','time'],sst_gradient)},/error in this line
                   coords={'lat':(selected_sst.lat.values),
                           'lon':(selected_sst.lon.values),
                           'time':(selected_sst.time.values)})
`
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py
>   in as_variable(obj, name)
>       106         try:
>   --> 107             obj = Variable(*obj)
>       108         except (TypeError, ValueError) as error:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py
>   in **init**(self, dims, data, attrs, encoding, fastpath)
>       308         self._data = as_compatible_data(data, fastpath=fastpath)
>   --> 309         self._dims = self._parse_dimensions(dims)
>       310         self._attrs = None
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py
>   in _parse_dimensions(self, dims)
>       499                 "dimensions %s must have the same length as the "
>   --> 500                 "number of data dimensions, ndim=%s" % (dims, self.ndim)
>       501             )
>
> ValueError: dimensions ('lat', 'lon', 'time') must have the same
>   length as the number of data dimensions, ndim=0
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         3                         coords={'lats':(selected_sst.lat.values),
>         4                                 'lons':(selected_sst.lon.values),
>   ----> 5                                 'times':(selected_sst.time.values)})
>         6 
>         7
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py
>   in **init**(self, data_vars, coords, attrs, compat)
>       533 
>       534         variables, coord_names, dims, indexes = merge_data_and_coords(
>   --> 535             data_vars, coords, compat=compat
>       536         )
>       537
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py
>   in merge_data_and_coords(data, coords, compat, join)
>       465     indexes = dict(_extract_indexes_from_coords(coords))
>       466     return merge_core(
>   --> 467         objects, compat, join, explicit_coords=explicit_coords, indexes=indexes
>       468     )
>       469
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py
>   in merge_core(objects, compat, join, priority_arg, explicit_coords,
>   indexes, fill_value)
>       550         coerced, join=join, copy=False, indexes=indexes, fill_value=fill_value
>       551     )
>   --> 552     collected = collect_variables_and_indexes(aligned)
>       553 
>       554     prioritized = _get_priority_vars_and_indexes(aligned, priority_arg, compat=compat)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py
>   in collect_variables_and_indexes(list_of_mappings)
>       275                 append_all(coords, indexes)
>       276 
>   --> 277             variable = as_variable(variable, name=name)
>       278             if variable.dims == (name,):
>       279                 variable = variable.to_index_variable()
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py
>   in as_variable(obj, name)
>       111                 "Could not convert tuple of form "
>       112                 "(dims, data[, attrs, encoding]): "
>   --> 113                 "{} to Variable.".format(obj)
>       114             )
>       115     elif utils.is_scalar(obj):
>
> ValueError: Could not convert tuple of form (dims, data[, attrs,
>   encoding]): (['lat', 'lon', 'time'],  Dimensions:
>   (lat: 600, lon: 4320, sst.lat: 72, sst.lon: 600, sst.time: 4320, time:
>   72) Coordinates:   * lat           (lat) float32 -40.041668 -40.12501
>   ... -89.87501 -89.958336   * lon           (lon) float32 -179.95833
>   -179.875 ... 179.87502 179.95836   * time          (time) datetime64[ns] 2005-01-15 2005-02-15 ... 2010-12-15 Dimensions without
>   coordinates: sst.lat, sst.lon, sst.time Data variables:
>       sst_gradient  (sst.lat, sst.lon, sst.time) float32 2.7785575e-08 ... nan) to Variable.

Comment: You would need to add some information about the source data (shape, dimensions etc), How should we know otherwise why you are facing these problems.

For xarray.Datasets the output of ds.info() would be nice, So the output of `sst_selected.info()` would be interesting, as well as information about sst_gradient.

Comment: the selected sst is taken as latitude below 40 degree and it is having shape of (72, 600, 4320). the  sst_gradient is computed using np.gradient::sst_gradient= np.gradient(selected_sst.values,float(dy)*1e3,edge_order=2, axis=1). it is having a length of (72).

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent function for `numpy.gradient` is `xarray.DataSet.differentiate`.

You can find details here: [xarray differentiate](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.differentiate.html)

Comment: i tried using, but it is not working.it is showing same error again.